# HTTP OPTIONS method with Java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I need to create a simple HTTP client program with Java.

I've not found any example of implementation in Java that allows calling the OPTIONS method to get the Allow header with the allowed methods on the server.

I tried using:

```
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
System.out.println(http.getHeaderFields());
```

But the field `Allow: GET, POST ...` is not included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: In the case,  my request message was not correct edited. I've edited the request and now it's working well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection object fires a GET request by default. You need to [set the request method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getRequestMethod--) to OPTIONS.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
System.out.println(conn.getRequestMethod()); // GET
conn.setRequestMethod("OPTIONS");
System.out.println(conn.getHeaderField("Allow")); // depends
```